# Perl push values in a hash

Tags: perl, hash, perl-data-structures

I am always confusing or don't know how to handle hash in perl.

So here is the problem,

Considering the whole thing, i am trying to change the key name in the below hash.

```
my %hash_new = {
  'customername' => 'Lee & toys',
  'employee_name' => 'Checngwang',
  'customer_id' => 'X82349K',
  'customer_address' => 'classic denver ranch, meadows drive',
  'types' => 'category la',
};

my %selectCols = ('customername' => 'CUSTOMERNAME','employee_name' => 'EMP_NAME','customer_id' => 'cusid','customer_address' => 'cusaddr','types' => 'Typs');

my %new_hash = ();

foreach my $hash_keys (keys %hash_new){
   my $newKey = $selectCols{$hash_keys};
   $new_hash{$newKey} = $hash_new{$hash_keys};
}

print Dumper %new_hash;
```

Output of %new_hash is something like a key value combination of continuous string as below,

```
CUTOMERNAMELee & toysEMP_NAMEChecngwangcus_idX82349Kcusaddrclassic denver ranch, meadows driveTypscategory la
```

But instead of this, i need the hash like,

```
$VAR1 = {
      'CUSTOMERNAME' => 'Lee & toys',
      'EMP_NAME' => 'Checngwang',
      'cusid' => 'X82349K',
      'cusaddr' => 'classic denver ranch, meadows drive',
      'Typs' => 'category la',
    };
```

Please help me around this!

Comment: I'm sorry, you're going to have to expand a bit - I can't follow what you're asking. I don't see any print statements in your code example.

Comment: you're fine! I just updated the print statement

Comment: I'm confused. What's your input and what's the desired output?

Comment: I am sorry for the confusion. Updated the question. Hope you get it now!

Comment: For a _hash_ you need parenthesis -- `my %h = ( )`; if you use curlies you are working with a _hash reference_, which is a scalar -- `my $rh = { ... }`. You cannot really say `%hash = { ... }` (WRONG). The answer by [yonyon100](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4819884/yonyon100) spells it out.  With `use warnings;` at the beginning of your program you'd hear about this.  Please always `use warnings;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, then this works:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;


my %hash_new = (
  'customername' => 'Lee & toys',
  'employee_name' => 'Checngwang',
  'customer_id' => 'X82349K',
  'customer_address' => 'classic denver ranch, meadows drive',
  'types' => 'category la'
);

my %selectCols = (
  'customername' => 'CUSTOMERNAME',
  'employee_name' => 'EMP_NAME',
  'customer_id' => 'cusid',
  'customer_address' => 'cusaddr',
  'types' => 'Typs'
);

my %new_hash = ();

foreach my $hash_keys (keys %hash_new){
   my $newKey = $selectCols{$hash_keys};
   $new_hash{$newKey} = $hash_new{$hash_keys};
}

print Dumper \%new_hash;
```

The only code I changed in your code was using  `()` instead of `{}` in `%hash_new` and escaped the `%` in the `Dumper` statement. The `%` should be escaped because `Dumper` expects a reference, not a hash (that's true also for all other Perl variable types in use with `Dumper`).

Output:

```
$VAR1 = {
      'Typs' => 'category la',
      'cusaddr' => 'classic denver ranch, meadows drive',
      'EMP_NAME' => 'Checngwang',
      'cusid' => 'X82349K',
      'CUSTOMERNAME' => 'Lee & toys'
    };
```

Also, don't use confusing names like `%hash_new` and `%new_hash`. It's - well - confusing.

Comment: I am sorry for the variable confusion! It works fine :)